# Update CA Bundle on Redhat 6

Tags: linux, ssl, redhat, certificate-authority

I have a few Redhat 6 servers that are unable to verify the certificate of an HTTPS site.  I have checked, and they don't appear to have a very current CA bundle.  The file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` was last modified in 2010.  I checked which package is responsible for updating this file by doing `rpm -qf /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, and it appears that it is part of `ca-certificates` package.  I tried `yum install ca-certificates`, and the latest version is already installed.  Is there a package available for Redhat 6 that contains a newer CA bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. I recommend using http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and making an rpm (easily done with fpm) or distributing it with your configuration management system.

Comment: Thanks! I have done what you recommended, but it just seems odd that this is not better managed by the system updates.

Comment: Nowadays it's recommended to use `update-ca-trust` utility as @Adam Williamson mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Since Mark's answer was posted, we (RH) have started updating the distribution bundle more proactively, and introduced an improved system for managing the trust store. There were updates to RHEL 6's ca-certificates in October and December of 2013, and in July and August of 2014, and further updates will be made when appropriate. See `man update-ca-trust` for details of the new system, after updating to the latest version of the package.